# How to create static library from an existing framework in iOS?

Tags: ios, frameworks, xamarin.ios, static-libraries

I have been provided with a framework by a third party vendor for an iPhone hardware accessory. So I have a folder like Device.framework. Inside that folder is a binary file and a set of .h files. There are instructions for how to add this to an iOS project and use the classes contained within. However, I'm actually using MonoTouch and want to use a static library.

Is there a way to create a static library that makes all the classes from the framework available in the static library? So in my MonoTouch project I would link in the static library and have access to that framework.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A *.framework is simply a package containing: the static library, headers, associated meta data. Copy and paste the .framework and extract the static *.a file and related header files.

Then it's simply a matter of using the MonoTouch btouch tool to bind the static library for use in your MonoTouch project. There is a great example of how to bind a native library to MonoTouch on Github. With guidance on targeting simulator + device and using the LinkWith attribute to embed the static library in a single *.dll:

- https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/BindingSample

Also, make sure to check out the btouch Reference documentation here:

- http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types

Comment: I've accepted this one one as the answer simply because it has the link to the BindingSample which was useful. Thanks to both guys for taking time to answer

Comment: @JWB with your latest upvote (mine ;-) you now have enough reputation points to upvote both answers :-)

Comment: @Jeff-SoftwareResults Did you figure out how you can create a binding library dll from *.framework?

Comment: @Anand I think I did looking at my comment on the answer below. But that was six years ago, I simply don't remember the details. Sorry

Answer (score 8):

Rename that binary file to `Device.a`. You can do that as the framework you mention is not done by Apple, hence it has to be a static library and not a dynamic one.

Make sure your project links that library (`Device.a`).

Include the headers in your project and reference them where appropriate.

Comment: I renamed the file as you suggested and did 'nm filename.a' and I can indeed see all the classes there. I'll need to do further work work to check it all hangs together properly but its looking good. Thanks

Comment: Wow, useful piece of trivia that I did not know!

Comment: When I tried with the BrotherPrinterSDK, I am getting a response like below Could not create an native instance of the type 'bpsdkBinding.BRPtouchPrintInfo': the native class hasn't been loaded.
It is possible to ignore this condition by setting ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.